# Struggling with a data scrape

Tags: python, selenium

https://www.solopress.com/business-cards/economy/

Using Python Selenium.
I am trying to scrape the pricing data in the table below. So far I have worked out how to loop through the Size Selector. but I can't work out how to loop through other selectors (Printed Sides etc). Nothing seems to have a unique identifier.

Size Xpath

```
//*[@id="options"]/div/a/span[2]
```

Printed sides Xpath

```
//*[@id="options"]/div/a/span[2]
```

This is the code I have been using to loop through the Sizes Selector which works.

```
def nextSize():
    global c
    global tablecounter
    global cellnum

    c = 2
    global dropdownSize
    dropdownSize = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="options"]/div/div/ul/li/ul/li/div')
    for i in dropdownSize:
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        time.sleep(5)
        tableExtractor()
        c = str(c)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[3]/div/a/span[3]/b').click()
        time.sleep(5)
        op = '//*[@id="options"]/div/div/ul/li/ul/li[%s]/div' % c
        try:
            getSize = driver.find_element_by_xpath(op)
            sizeName = getSize.get_attribute('innerHTML')
            sizeName = sizeName.lstrip()
            sizeName = sizeName.rstrip()
            print sizeName
            ws.cell(row=cellnum,column=1).value = sizeName
            ws.cell(row=cellnum,column=2).value = sideName
            cellnum += 1
        except:
            break
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(op).click()
            c = int(c)
            c += 1
        except:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[3]/div/a/span[3]/b').click()
            break

nextSize()
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ? Are you getting some error?

Comment: Sorry, the problem was that I couldn't figure out a unique way to identify the second 'Selector' drop down. The accepted answer has found a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like both elements could be identified by the following xPaths since they have different innerHTML:

```
//*[@class="select2-result-label ui-select-choices-row-inner" and text()[contains(., "Single Sided")]]
```

And

```
//*[@class="select2-result-label ui-select-choices-row-inner" and text()[contains(., "Double Sided")]]
```

Comment: This worked, I didn't realise I could do this. To clarify, what is happening with the '.' in contains? that's the only part I can't understand.

Comment: It tells the xPath to stay at the current node, as opposed to eg `/` which indicates the root of the document.